# Apache POI Word get the last row index in the table for each page

Tags: java, apache-poi

I use Apache POI to generating word document (docx)  contains table ,This table spans more than four pages. Is there a way to get the last row index in the table for each page

Comment: Getting the last row index in the table for each page is only possible after rendering the pages. This is not possible using `apache poi` since it does not rendering the pages. But there is a possibility to [repeat table header on subsequent pages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repeat-table-header-on-subsequent-pages-2ff677e0-3150-464a-a283-fa52794b4b41) and there are possibilities to [keep text together](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keep-text-together-af94e5b8-3a5a-4cb0-9c53-dea56b43d96d). So why do you think you will need the last row index in the table for each page?